# Clamp panning to svg boundaries with panzoom.svg.js

Tags: javascript, svg.js

In the following code, I set up margins so that it would not be able to pan outside of the svg boundaries as follows:

```js
const map = SVG('#map')
        .size(500, 500)
        // @ts-ignore: next-line
        .panZoom({
          zoomMin: 1,
          margins: {
            top: 500,
            left: 500,
            bottom: 500,
            right: 500,
          },
        })
        .zoom(1);
```

I thought that I could adjust adjust the margins in the zoom callback by multiplying the values with the zoom `level`, but that does not work and causes the panning to stop working:

```js
map.on('zoom', event => {
 const { level } = event.detail
 map.panZoom({
  margins: {
    top: 500 * level,
    left: 500 * level,
    bottom: 500 * level,
    right: 500 * level
   }
 })
})
```

Comment: It's doing a lot automatically. You probably just want your svg width and height as margin

Comment: I guess what I want is to have a viewbox of say 400x400 with 500x500 svg in it and it works at the default zoom level. but as soon as I zoom in, I am unable to pan to the edges of the svg: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-chandrasekhar-rz9gw?file=/src/App.tsx:722-725

Comment: Don't call panzoom in the zoom handler. Call it once and never again!